# Is there a Powerpoint (PPT) to text/html converter?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format, presentation

Is there a ppt to text/html converter for Ubuntu/*nix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found a python based command line converter called [unoconv](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unoconv) (install from Software Center or with `apt-get`)
 which will allow you to convert from and to anything openoffice can deal with including ppt, txt and html plus as it is cli based so you can batch process nicely :)

- [Homepage of unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice allows you to export presentations in html or plain text, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `catppt` from the [catdoc [image: Install catdoc]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/catdoc) package.